# Log4j SMTPAppender

Tags: java, email, log4j

I have some problems trying to play with `SMTPAppender`. Here is my property file concerning the SMTPAppender:

```
#Email config
log4j.appender.mail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
#defines how often emails are send
log4j.appender.mail.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPHost=smtp.me.com
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPUsername=username
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPPassword=something
log4j.appender.mail.From=Myselft@mac.com
log4j.appender.mail.To=ABeautifulGirlWaitingForMe@SomeWhere.com
log4j.appender.mail.Subject="Application.log error occurred"
log4j.appender.mail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mail.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p [%c] %n%m%n
```

When I launch my program, I have this error message:

```
log4j:ERROR Error occured while sending e-mail notification.
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.me.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.me.com
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1389)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
```

I have to say that I'm totally new in the mail world. And as far as I'm aware smt.me.com exist, it's Apple Mobile Me service.

I wonder if there is a possibility that the problem is due to a special configuration in my work computer? Maybe they can scan and stop certain process like this one?

Comment: What happens if you try to telnet to smtp.me.com from that machine?

Comment: Well it does not seem to work : 
Connecting To smtp.me.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed

Comment: Not on port 23 (unless your SMTP server is listening on port 23 which is very unlikely). Try port 25 instead.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, try

```
dig smtp.me.com
```

or

```
nslookup smtp.me.com
```

On the same workstation where your are running your program.
If the above commands don't return a meaningful IP address then you have a DNS issues.

You will need to create an A record for `smtp.me.com`.

Comment: Thanks, yes nslookup return me an error message ... 
I will probably have to wait for try at home ?

Comment: @Farid. You can use `/etc/hosts` file to override DNS/provide temporary value for the host name for your test.
If you are using Windows, it's found in rather peculiar place: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. 
Just add line `192.168.0.xxx smtp.me.com`